# Cannot call a functoin that is declared in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have declared a function in JavaScript, and inside it some JQuery code, and I'm calling this function inside a click event, and its not getting called.
And when I define an function with function keyword its saying expecting a function, so I have to use the functions as expression. The function is getting called when its outside the click event, like getting called globally when the document is ready.

JavaScript

```
var item_width = $('.item-slider').width();
var item_margin = (item_width-600)/5; //sum of 4 elements divided by 5 margin spaces
var items = $('ul.item-slider>li');
var x = 0;
$.each(items,function(index){
    $(this).data("id",x);
    x = x+1; 
});   

var x = function(){
    $.each(items,function(index){ 
        var pos = $(this).data('id');

        if($(this).data('id') < 1){
            var left =(pos-1) * 150 + (pos-1) * 10;
            -Math.abs(left);
            $(this).css("left",left);
        }
        else if($(this).data('id') === 1){
            $(this).css("left", 0);
            console.log("positon is set to" + $(this).css("left"));
        }        
        else if($(this).data('id') > 1){
            var left = (pos-1) * 150 + (pos-1) * 10;
            $(this).css("left", left);
            console.log("positon is set to  " + $(this).css("left"));
        }
    });
}

// commented x();

$(".explore_matches > button[name = 'pre']").click(function(){
    $.each(items,function(index){
       console.log("each working");
        $(this).data('id',"abc");
    })
    x();
    console.log("skipped");
});
```

Comment: You tries to redeclare `x` many times. `var x = 0;`, `var x = function() {}`. Thats wrong. You can decalre it only once.

Comment: even if I change to another variable name, it still wont work,

Comment: jQuery and HTML in a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var item_width = $('.item-slider').width();
var item_margin = (item_width-600)/5; //sum of 4 elements divided by 5 margin spaces
var items = $('ul.item-slider>li');
var x = 0;
$.each(items,function(index){
    $(this).data("id",x);
    x = x+1; 
});   

function needToCall(){
    $.each(items,function(index){ 
        var pos = $(this).data('id');

        if($(this).data('id') < 1){
            var left =(pos-1) * 150 + (pos-1) * 10;
            -Math.abs(left);
            $(this).css("left",left);
        }
        else if($(this).data('id') === 1){
            $(this).css("left", 0);
            console.log("positon is set to" + $(this).css("left"));
        }        
        else if($(this).data('id') > 1){
            var left = (pos-1) * 150 + (pos-1) * 10;
            $(this).css("left", left);
            console.log("positon is set to  " + $(this).css("left"));
        }
    });
}



$(".explore_matches > button[name = 'pre']").click(function(){
    $.each(items,function(index){
       console.log("each working");
        $(this).data('id',"abc");
    })
   needToCall();
    console.log("skipped");
});
```